# Using spring to instantiate with static factory methods?

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring3. I have below classes.

### Transport.java

```
package com.net.core.ioc;

public interface Transport {
  public void getTransport();
}
```

### Car.java

```
package com.net.core.ioc;

    public class Car implements Transport{
        public void getTransport(){
            System.out.println("Transport type is Car");
        }
    }
```

### Bus.java

```
package com.net.core.ioc;

    public class Bus implements Transport {
        public void getTransport() {
            System.out.println("Transport type is Car");
        }
```

### SpringService.java

```
package com.net.core.ioc;

    public class SpringService {
        private static SpringService service = new SpringService();

        //Static factory method
        public static SpringService createService(){
            return service;
        }

        //Instance factory methods
        public Transport createCarInstance(){
        return new Car();
        }

    public Transport createBusInstance(){
            return new Bus();
        }

    }
 }
```

### config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="javabeat.net.core.ioc"/>
        <bean id="springServiceStaticFactory" factory-method="createService"/>
        <bean id="springServiceCarInstance" factory-bean="springServiceStaticFactory" factory-method="createCarInstance"/>
        <bean id="springServiceBusInstance" factory-bean="springServiceStaticFactory" factory-method="createBusInstance"/>
    </beans>
```

Now my question is does spring manage Car and Bus instances which are being instantiated using SpringService.java class?Because i have to annotate Car and Bus classes with @Transactional annotation. Is it possible?

Comment: Why would a bus say it's a Car transport type?

Answer (score 0):

Spring will manage your `Car` and `Bus` instances as they are part of the `ApplicationContext`. What you are doing is basically the same as normally would happen with a Spring `FactoryBean` but you are now using your own mechanism.

However in your current setup the `Car` and `Bus` beans are singletons as they will be created once, not sure if that is what you want.

If you want to pass in values to the constructor simply modify your factory method.

```
public Transport createCarInstance(String name){
    return new Car(name);
}
```

Your bean definition should tell that it is a prototype scoped bean

```
    <bean id="springServiceCarInstance" factory-bean="springServiceStaticFactory" factory-method="createCarInstance" scope="prototype" />
```

Now in your code you can do a lookup and pass arguments to the lookup method (See [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)).

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx;

public void myMethod() {
    Car car = ctx.getBean(Car.class, "Mercedes"); 
}
```

The code above should give you a fresh `Car` instance with the name *Mercedes*.

Comment: Denium, thanks much for ur answer. How does spring manage Car and Bus since they are not declared in Spring configuration file?

Comment: Yes they are, through the factory methods.

Comment: Interesting, just suppose this scenario @M.Deinum , what will happend if Car have some Autowired of dependencies, when you instantiate the object with new , the newly created instance is going to autowired the needed dependencies? I think not, but please correct me if I´m wrong.

Comment: My point is that Factory is managed by Spring but the objects that are provided by the factory are not, it sounds just create the instance but the life cycle of those beans are not managed by spring, do you have any link you can share to me, will be great .

Comment: With his current configuration the resulting beans are managed by Spring as those are singletons. It isn't any different then a normal Spring `FactoryBean`. The result of the factory bean is treated as any other Spring bean.